# Is there a correct syntax highlighting for Aura Components in VSCode?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visualstudiocode, syntax-highlighting

When editing Aura Components (`.cmp` files) in VSCode it shows an error, even with the `Aura Components` extension installed.

How do I have syntax highlighting enabled without showing errors for Aura code style?

[image: HTML]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot it appears you refer to the VSCode HTML built-in style checker.

In VSCode's Settings you can find this as `HTML: Validate: Styles`. Toggle this. The underlying property is `html.validate.styles`, which can be true or false.